# Save big lists to csv/pickle files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning to use pandas to save data to csv and pickle files, using the following script:

```
data = {'Product': [['Desktop Computer' * 30]],
    'Price': [['850' * 30]]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Product', 'Price'])
df.to_csv('sample_csv.csv')
df.to_pickle('sample_pickle.pkl')
```

The csv file could be saved correctly, but the pickle file had some trash in it. Please see the attached pictures "correct_small_csv.png" and "pickle_withtrash.png".

[image]
[image]

Another thing I found is if the list size in data increases from 30 to 3000. The saved csv file would be messed up also. Basically the list of the 3000 'Desktop Computer' will be saved in two cells in the csv file. Please see the picture "Messed_big_csv.png".[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, it really isn't clear what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a list of strings do this `'Price': [['10'] * 30]` instead of this `'Price': [['10' * 30]]`. In other case you will have a list with one string element like ['10101010101....'] instead of ['10', '10', ....]

I've tried your solution with saving and it worked well for me for 30 and 3k items. Maybe there is a glitch or something like this? For sure everything is fine with code so I suggest there's something with an excel file visualization. I'm not sure but check the max length of a cell in csv/excel. Maybe it can't store 3k of 'Desktop Computer' in one cell.

Moreover pickle is a binary file so maybe you have no need to open it as text file.

Try to read both in pandas and see what will happen (everything should be just fine)